# What keyboard protocol do IBM 3151 Terminals speak over RJ45

Tags: keyboards, ibm, terminal, serial

I've recently acquired an **IBM 3151 Terminal** without keyboard and I'm not willing to spend any money on an original keyboard. This is why I've tried searching Google for any datasheets of the IBM RJ45 keyboard interface protocol, to no avail.

The connector is an **RJ45** port.

Does anyone know what protocol those terminals used, so I can emulate the keyboard or possibly adapt a PS/2 keyboard? Are there any converters out there I just haven't found?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a **whole lot more** keys on a 3151 kb than a PC kb; You're going to have trouble just adapting a PS/2 kb.  Besides, having the original kb is part of the experience.

Comment: Anyway... Here's the reference manual: http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/3151/GA18-2634-0_IBM_3151_ASCII_Display_Station_Reference_Manual_Apr1987.pdf  It might help.  (I found it by looking at the References section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3101 (which I found by googling "IBM 3151 Terminal").)

Comment: I have no direct knowledge of the 3151, but some other IBM terminals of that era (such as the 3179) use the same protocol as AT / PS/2 keyboards, with scancode set 3.

Comment: @RonJohn Thanks for the link. I agree, it would be nice to have an original keyboard, but unfortunately I don't have much money to spare, as I'm just some student interested in this kind of stuff. This is why I have to do this on a budget.